# How do I make this punched-out text style in Photoshop?

Tags: text, photoshop-effects, style-identification

[image: What's this style?]

Can someone tell me how to do this stencil style? I've tried searching for "stencil text style" and others but it only shows stencil fonts. I think this is not a font but is made with photoshop. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: This is also an actual typeface. https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/blackout

Answer (score 1):

There’s a really cool and a little crazy way to do it, using `Blend If` under Layer → Layer Style → Blending Options:

- Draw everything as black and white, with white where you want solid colour, and black where you want clear. You can use anything, including text and shape layers.
- Make sure you have a solid black fill as a bottom layer (in the objects you’d like to use this technique for).
- Encase the text, other layers and black background in a group.
- Open Layer → Layer Style → Blending Options for the Group.
- Hold the option key and drag the leftmost Blend If / This Layer handle. Drag it all the way to the right. Click OK.
- Encase that Group in another Group.
- Use a Color Overlay Layer Style on the new Group (I’ve filled it with white).
- You can now place an image below and it’ll show through. You can even edit the text, change font etc etc.

[image: Blend If]

I’ve written more about the technique here: http://bjango.com/articles/blendif/

Answer (score 0):

It could be text typed onto a layer mask, with the layer mask then being used on the white rectangle graphic.

So actual steps:

1. Create a white rectangle (I'd use a shape layer myself)
2. Add a layer mask to the rectangle layer/shape
3. Select the layer mask
4. Use the text tool to write text on the layer mask
5. You should now see the underlying background where the text in the layer mask overlays the rectangle.